# Selecting a 2013 workflow for use with Information Management Policy retention

Tags: workflow, workflow-manager, information-management, retention

I have a 365 tenant where I need to have a workflow triggered on a custom date field set by the user, to do a review before the doc validity expires.

I've done the workflow in both 2010 and 2013 versions to test...

[image: Workflows in SPD]

When I add a retention stage and go to 'Start a workflow', only the 2010 workflow is an option:

[image: Retention options... but where's the 2013 flow?]

I've checked if it's the same for library and content-type based retention (it is) and when using a different date field (it is). Both of the workflows run OK if started manually (it just checks the fields are OK then sends an email).

I saw this on one of our 2013 O/P installs as well but never raised it with MS - it feels like retention wasn't properly interfaced with the 2013 onwards workflow engine.

Anyone?

Comment: I realised just after posting this it may be the workflow type, but having a Reusable rather than a List also made no difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got in touch with MS about this - as I thought, the 2013 workflows aren't exposed to the IMP interface because of the different engine type. You use 2010 workflows or nothing.